# Swift 5 LLDB error: warning: <EXPR>:12:9: warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result' was never used

Tags: swift, uitableview, dictionary, generics, lldb

Full Error Message:

```
error: warning: <EXPR>:12:9: warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it
    var $__lldb_error_result = __lldb_tmp_error
    ~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    _

error: <EXPR>:19:5: error: use of unresolved identifier '$__lldb_injected_self'
    $__lldb_injected_self.$__lldb_wrapped_expr_7(
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This error appears in Console when I interrogate the value of a `Dictionary<String, String>` property within a generic `UITableViewController` (TVC).

More Detail...

I have a generic TVC (noted above) that is more or less based on the framework outlined in the book "Core Data" by Florian Kugler and Daniel Eggert and takes, amongst other things, a generic value of T.

```
class TVCDataSource_List<T: Managed, etc...>
```

This generic TVC includes a dictionary that is designed to hold a list of longer 'alternative' names for the TVC's section headers.

```
var dictionarySectionData: [String: String] = [:]
```

I've elected to program the TVC this way because it seems more efficient to hold a reference to a name as a short two character `String` in the data model attribute (section identifier) than a long name as a `String`.

I've tried populating this dictionary at many different places in code, most of which work but all with the same outcome, specifically:

- I step through the code using the debugger and, as expected, the dictionary is populated via a single fetch request to the persistent store;
- Immediately following, a call to `print(dictionarySectionData.description)` to the console, prints out a properly populated dictionary, as expected;
- Interrogating LLDB with `p dictionarySectionData` (or `po`) immediately before and after this `print` to console, produces the Full Error Message detailed at the start of this question;
- At the same time, the Assistant Editor Variable Viewer shows the dictionary to be empty, which surprisingly conflicts with the print;
- I continue to step through the code to construct the TVC, as the dictionary no longer has its key value pairs, I cannot recall the value for my section header and as expected, the console reports "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

I've done a bit of simple research:

1. This [Blog](http://scottberrevoets.com/2018/08/08/re-binding-self-the-debuggers-breaking-point/) by Scott Berrevoets titled "Re-binding self: the debugger's break(ing) point".
2. This [Swift Bug Report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-6156) by Keith Smiley titled "LLDB: warning: initialization of variable '$__lldb_error_result'".
3. This [Swift Bug Report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3886) by Zev Eisenberg titled "error: use of undeclared type '$__lldb_context' in NSAttributedString extension".

It seems that I may have either:

- stumbled across a bug in the compiler; or
- attempted to set the value for the dictionary within the generic TVC such that the compiler interprets an attempt to re-bind to self??

Frankly neither of which I understand and from my shallow knowledge of the compiler and Swift, would take me months, possibly years of learning and experience. Which I'm happy to slowly accumulate over time.

I do have a satisfactory solution... instead of building a dictionary of the longer 'alternative' names for the TVC's section headers at the beginning of the TVC lifecycle, I run a fetch request EACH TIME the code resolves the name for the current TVC section header. This works perfectly and does not block the UI (yet).

However, it really annoys me that I cannot run one fetch at the start of the construction of my generic TVC to prepare a concise dictionary of longer 'alternative' names for the TVC's section headers and instead have to run a fetch for each section that the user decides to scroll through. To perform one fetch and hold a dictionary of 12-15 key value pairs in memory seems far more efficient that running many fetches.

Has any one experienced this problem?

If so, are you able to offer any advice?

---

### UPDATE

The problem seems to be with my use - or perhaps more correctly, my misuse - of the explicitly unwrapped `Optional`.

Here is the code I use to populate the dictionary...

```
func createDictionaryOfSectionHeaderText() {

    let request = Types.preparedFetchRequest
    // noting .preparedFetchRequest is a static var, available through generics

    let key = "typeParent.typeParentName"
    let name = "Taxonomy"
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", argumentArray: [key, name])

    request.predicate = predicate

    var results: [Types] = []

    do {

        results = try <<My NSManagedObjectContext>>.fetch(request)
    }
    catch {

        let fetchError = error
        print(fetchError)
    }

    for type in results {

        let formatSortOrder = String(format: "%02d", type.sortOrder)
        dictionarySectionData[formatSortOrder] = type.typeName
    }
}
```

There were two elements of code that caused the error message...

A. As above in the `func createDictionaryOfSectionHeaderText()`

```
let stringSortOrder = String(type.sortOrder)
let formatSortOrder = String(format: "%02d", stringSortOrder)
```

...which was feeding a string into the format "%02d", uncertain of the effect... TBA.

(Now changed from those two lines to the single `let formatSortOrder = String(format: "%02d", type.sortOrder)` - which of course works.)

B. Within the `UITableViewDelegate` method `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

```
stringHeaderText = dictionarySectionData[stringSectionName]!
// "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
```

...which, following more thought on the matter, is exactly as expected when explicitly unwrapping the Optional, when that Optional is nil!!

So, when I change the setter to `stringHeaderText` by removing the instruction to explicitly unwrap, and instead offer a default value when nil, my programming problem disappears.

```
stringHeaderText = dictionarySectionData[stringSectionName] ?? "ERROR"
```

I may even provide an answer if/when I understand this better.

Comment: Yes, almost every `po` will print out this messages. Debugging in Xcode was always hard and slow, and every year it gets worse. They got a new keyword `v`, but that is totally useless since a lot of variables are not available. I hate Xcode :( Comparing to IntelliJ, Xcode is really, really crappy.

Comment: @J.Doe Technical note - this has nothing to do with Xcode but with the LLVM debugger.

Comment: Could you maybe add more code related to the generic class? Maybe some wrong usage of `dynamic` or `NSManaged` could be the problem?

Comment: @Sulthan thanks for the comment... sure I can include code but it would be a very large chunk across at least three classes to be able to present in context. All entity attributes function correctly and using the "satisfactory solution" that I mention the project Builds and Runs, so unless I'm missing something, I'm fairly certain it is not related to the `NSManagedObject` subclass/es. PS writing in Swift so no use of `dynamic`.

Answer (score -2):

These issues should be solved in XCode 12.
There were indeed a lot of bugs in XCode 10 & 11, especially when it came to Generics

Comment: This is not the answer to the problem!

Comment: @Abhishek because there is no answer to this problem. Xcode sucks to the point where you can not even print a variable in the console. "po true" in a breakpoint in a class? Prints true. "po true" in a breakpoint in another class? sorry mate, that lldb thing doesn't work from this class. This problem has been for years. Period.